# Equivalents of PubMed in other fields

Tags: literature-review, literature-search, pubmed

I work in biomedical sciences, and whenever I need to look up an article - or find recent references about a certain field of biology - I just go to PubMed, because it collects information from the vast majority of "serious" journals (from Cell/Nature/Science to niche publications).

Are there equivalents of PubMed (comprehensive and easy to use) in other fields, except for Google Scholar and ArXiv? For example, in physics, chemistry, geology, electronics...?

Comment: For mathematics there is [Mathematical Reviews](http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/math-reviews) and [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Unlike PubMed, many of the discipline specific indexing and abstract services tend to be run as proprietary services:

- For Engineering there is [Engineering Village](https://www.engineeringvillage.com/home.url)
- For Chemistry there is the [Chemical Abstracts Service (CAS) SciFinder](https://www.cas.org/products/scifinder)
- For Theology and Religious Studies there is [Index Theologicus](https://www.ixtheo.de/)
- For Philosophy there is [The Philosopher's Index](https://philindex.org/) and [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/)
- For Geology there is [GEOBASE](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/engineering-village/content/geobase) and GeoRef
- For Economics there is [EconLit](https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/) and [RePEc](http://repec.org/)
- For Mathematics there is [Mathematical Reviews](http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/math-reviews) and [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/) (hattip Dave Renfro)
- For Electronics and Computer Science there is [IEEE Xplore](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp)
- For Agriculture there is [AGRICOLA](https://agricola.nal.usda.gov/) and [AGRIS](http://agris.fao.org/agris-search/index.do)

Wikipedia has quite a full list that might be of further interest:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_databases_and_search_engines